# I have an error when I run the python script

Tags: python-3.x

I'm doing an exercise from a book about decision trees.

I copy-pasted the whole code and it gives me the NameError: name 'dtc' is not defined

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uiuc-cse/data-fa14/gh-pages/data/iris.csv')

#print(df.describe())
#print(df.dtypes)

df['petal_width'].plot.hist()
#plt.show()

all_inputs = df[['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width']].values
all_classes = df['species'].values

(train_inputs, test_inputs, train_classes, test_classes) = train_test_split(all_inputs, all_classes, train_size=0.7, random_state=1)

classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier()
classifier.fit(train_inputs, train_classes)

print("Accuracy: ", dtc.score(test_inputs, test_classes))
```

Can anyone help me understand why this error occurs?

Comment: you need to check your variable names. You have never initialized the `dtc` variable in your code. Probably, you may want to use the `classifier.score`, since `classifier` is the variable that you have initialized for `Decision Tree Classifier`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex, you need to check the variables properly. You have declared `classifier` as variable for `DecisionTreeClassifier` but you are using `dtc` in the end. Replace `dtc` with `classifier`:

```sh
print("Accuracy: ", classifier.score(test_inputs, test_classes))
```